# How to Format Pre-populated Input Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, formatting

I am populating a telephone input field with data from an API call when the page loads.

I have a function that formats phone numbers to look like this: *+1 (888) 333 4444*. But the function is only working when there is a keyup event.  I am trying to get this pre-populated input value to be formatted with this same function.  I've tried changing the event from keyup to load, onload, but it has no affect.  I tried wrapping the function in a setTimeout delay, but that didn't work either.

I know I'm missing something simple...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label>Telephone</label>
      <input type="tel" onload="phoneMask()" value="<?= data.phone ?>"/>
    </form>

  <script>
  //Format telephone numbers
  function phoneMask() { 
      var num = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g,''); 
      $(this).val('+' + num.substring(0,1) + ' (' + num.substring(1,4) + ') ' + num.substring(4,7) + ' ' + num.substring(7,18)); 
  }; 
  $('[type="tel"]').keyup(phoneMask)
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of the page, in the script section add this:

```
  function phoneMask() { 
    var num = $("input[type=tel]").val().replace(/\D/g,''); 
  $("input[type=tel]").val('+' + num.substring(0,1) + ' (' + num.substring(1,4) + ') ' + num.substring(4,7) + ' ' + num.substring(7,18));
  };

$(document).ready(function() {
    phoneMask();
} );
```

I have edited your phoneMask function.
This will call your phoneMask function once the page has loaded.

This works on the assumption that there is only going to be one box of type tel. Otherwise you will need to wrap the code in phoneMask areound an each with the selector using each.

Comment: I copied and pasted this immediately above the </script> tag but no luck.